# How to avoid page break after section titles in parallel columns

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, sections-paragraphs, parcolumns

I am using `parcolumns` to write some parallel columns documents. Everything works fine but some section titles show at the end of the page. I want them to be in the next page or at least some content is followed with the section title. How should I do? I used `\nobreak` or `\nopagebreak[4]` but it did not work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\sloppy

\newcommand{\mycol}[2]{%
\colchunk[1]{#1\\}
\colchunk[2]{#2\\}
\colplacechunks%
}

\newcommand{\mytitle}[2]{%
\colchunk[1]{%
\textbf{#1}\nopagebreak[4]
}
\colchunk[2]{%
\textbf{#2}\nopagebreak[4]
}
\colplacechunks\nopagebreak[4]
}

% Content starts here
\begin{document}
\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent]{2}

\mytitle{Section 1}{Section 1}
\mycol{content}{content}

\end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```